# Curve Fitting a data set with unknown formula (SciPy)

Tags: python, excel, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to curve fit a Waldram diagram so that I can plot my own. I used a program and got one curve from the diagram as point data, and want to figure out the formula.

I have a general knowledge of SciPy, and it appears to me that you need to have some sort of idea what the formula of the curve should be, which I do not. Is there a way to solve for a best fit curve without knowing a general formula?

[Waldram Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnqSN.jpg)

[Python Code for my custom points](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4tO0JwukJBdYTNHZ2ZJR29GVGM)

Comment: Assuming a polynomial is often a good idea also because functions can be expanded into (polynomial) series.

Comment: From the diagram your functions look rather periodic and symmetric, so you might get lucky fitting them with a few dct modes.

Comment: Extending @a_guest's comment, you can use numpy's [polyfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) with arbitrary degree until your curve is properly approximated (with acceptable error). It might not work, but is a good starting point.

Comment: Referring to @PaulPanzer 's comment: I didn't check the images, but in any case a series fit is a good try, so in case your functions show periodic features I suggest a [Fourier series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).

Comment: maybe this?  http://repository.ias.ac.in/82339/1/82339.pdf  waldram diagram math isn't explicitly spelled out but should be related to whats given

Comment: @f5r5e5d wow this looks really helpful! I'll get back to you on this! As for everyone else, I can get a decent fit with a polynomial, but it just isn't really reusable to recreate the model

Answer (score 2):

I fit the data you posted to over 400 known, named non-linear equations with four or less parameters using a genetic algorithm for initial parameter estimation,and chose what I thought was a good candidate equation from the sorted results as the Catenary Transform equation (with offset) - see attached graph.

```
y = a * cosh((bx + c) / a) + Offset

a = -9.8413881676827686E-02
b =  8.3564373717938123E-03
c = -3.8850547606358887E-04
Offset =  8.7774689075636331E+01


Degrees of freedom (error): 183
Degrees of freedom (regression): 3
Chi-squared: 2232.72609461
R-squared: 0.985367781841
R-squared adjusted: 0.985127909412
Model F-statistic: 4107.88262167
Model F-statistic p-value: 1.11022302463e-16
Model log-likelihood: -497.209347432
AIC: 5.36052778002
BIC: 5.42964240284
Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE): 3.45538879663

a = -9.8413881676827686E-02
       std err: 2.35115E-04
       t-stat: -6.41825E+00
       p-stat: 1.14906E-09
       95% confidence intervals: [-1.28667E-01, -6.81608E-02]

b = 8.3564373717938123E-03
       std err: 1.27107E-06
       t-stat: 7.41202E+00
       p-stat: 4.45377E-12
       95% confidence intervals: [6.13203E-03, 1.05808E-02]

c = -3.8850547606358887E-04
       std err: 3.74545E-07
       t-stat: -6.34812E-01
       p-stat: 5.26344E-01
       95% confidence intervals: [-1.59599E-03, 8.18980E-04]

Offset = 8.7774689075636331E+01
       std err: 2.53913E-01
       t-stat: 1.74192E+02
       p-stat: 0.00000E+00

       95% confidence intervals: [8.67805E+01, 8.87689E+01]


Coefficient Covariance Matrix
[  1.92706102e-05  -1.41684431e-06   1.54227770e-08  -4.40076630e-04]
[ -1.41684431e-06   1.04180031e-07  -1.21060089e-09   3.25700381e-05]
[  1.54227770e-08  -1.21060089e-09   3.06987009e-08  -8.90474871e-07]
[ -4.40076630e-04   3.25700381e-05  -8.90474871e-07   2.08113423e-02]
```

[image: output plot]

Comment: Ok, interesting, but how did you do it?

Comment: My open source online curve and surface fitting web site, http://zunzun.com, has a "function finder" using the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to find initial parameter estimates for non-linear equations, similar to the scipy module optimize.differential_evolution. I pasted your data into the web site, ran the function finder,  and looked for a good fit with a relatively few parameters.

Comment: I have data that has 4 input variable and 1 output variable. Can zunzun.com handle this? It sounds to me that zunzun.com can only handle function up to 2 input variables and 1 output variable, right?

Comment: I added my data to my question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333890/determine-the-function-formula-that-fits-my-data

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, you need some functional form of the model to fit to.

Ideally, you should be able to write a model with several parameters (which you then optimize for) from the meaning of your data. If that is not possible, you'll need to come up with something which is sensible based on your domain knowledge.